# How to use zgrep to display all words of a x size from a wordlist?

Tags: regex, linux, zcat, zgrep

I want to display all the words from my wordlist who start with a `w` and are 9 letters long. Yesterday I learnt a bit more on how to use `zgrep` so I came with :

`zgrep '\(^w\)\(^.........$\)' a.gz`

But this doesn't work and I think it's because I don't know how to do a `AND` between the two conditions. I found that it should be `(?=expr)(?=expr)` but I can't figure out how to build my command then

So how can I build my command using the `(?=expr)` ?

for example if I have a wordlist like this:

- Washington
- Sausage
- Walalalalalaaaa --> shouldn't match
- Wwwwwwwww --> should match

Comment: Maybe `zgrep '^w[[:alpha:]]\{8\}$' a.gz`?

Comment: Sadly not, I tried to do the things you told me yesterday with escaping the character but I can't figure out how to build this one

Comment: Will you please show a part of the wordlist and expected matches? `'^w[[:alpha:]]\{8\}$'` should match whole lines that start with `w` and then have 8 letters.

Comment: Oh yes now it works I think I did a mistake before sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
zgrep '^w[[:alpha:]]\{8\}$' a.gz
```

The [POSIX BRE pattern](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) will match a string that

- `^w` - starts with `w`
- `[[:alpha:]]\{8\}` - then has eight letters
- `$` - followed with with the end of string marker.

Also, see the [9.3 Basic Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).